# What is equivalent for @Formula(used in jpa), in webflux and r2dbc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, r2dbc

I have a `firstName` and `lastName` in my database, and I wanna make a `fullname` variable,
I used to set `@Formula` annotation in hibernate, but as I changed my services to reactive(webflux) and use `r2dbc`, I can't use it anymore!

my previous code was something like this:

```
public class OperatorUser implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @Formula("FIRST_NAME || \' \' || LAST_NAME")
    private String fullname;
```

Comment: Why not just write an ordinary SQL query?

Comment: @LukasEder yes, I think that would be a solution, but I have changed R2DBC to Hibernate Reactive and I had no problem with annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Formula is an `Hibernate/JPA` annotation and we cannot use it with `R2DBC`,
if we migrate **from an hibernate based project** to **webflux**, it's highly recommended to **use** **[Hibernate reactive](http://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.0/reference/html_single/) and [vert.x](https://vertx.io/)** to have access to all hibernate annotations and facilities.

also watching the youtube video in [this page](https://diego-pacheco.medium.com/hibernate-reactive-with-spring-boot-2-426b02b7457f) help you to understand it clearly.